# How can I use multiple substituteAll filters in the filter-spec config?

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

I need to be able to use multiple substituteAll filter expressions in my standalone.xml log config as shown below.

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <filter-spec value="substituteAll(&quot;(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]{14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11})&quot;,&quot;xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx&quot;),substituteAll(&quot;(&lt;ccSecurityCode&gt;.*&lt;/ccSecurityCode&gt;)&quot;,&quot;&lt;ccSecurityCode&gt;xxx&lt;/ccSecurityCode&gt;&quot;)"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %5p:%X{sessionId} - %C{1}.%M:(%L) | %m%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="website.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

We are using JBoss AS 7.2.  Is there any way to do this?  All my attempts to do this have failed.  I've tried separating them with commas (throws IllegalArgumentException "Extra data after filter expression"), adding them to any/all; but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to wrap it in an `all()` filter. Since the `substituteAll` filter always returns `true` and the `all()` filter ensures all filters return loggable that should work.